# File is being used by another process while using WriteAllText in c#

Tags: c#, file, writealltext

I am checking file is present if specified location and if so I am replacing single quote by &#39. For this I am using WriteAllText method. For my knowledge WriteAllText will be used to `Create file and write the text and close it, target file is already exists, it will be overwritten`.

I don't know why I am getting `System.IOException` while using

```
var file = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "test";
if (Directory.Exists(file))
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText(file + "\\test.txt");
    text = text.Replace("'", "&#39");
    File.WriteAllText(file + "\\test.txt", text);
}
```

**Note:** I am using this inside `Application_BeginRequest` method.

Suggest me how to avoid this exception ?

Comment: Just cross verify any other application (like notepad, etc..) using it..

Comment: When you get the `IOException` what does it say is the `InnerException`? That should give you an idea what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use your code like below

```
            var file = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "test.txt";
            if (File.Exists(file))
            {
                string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
                text = text.Replace("'", "&#39");
                File.WriteAllText(file, text);
            }
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,
You are asking on existence of Directory while using

```
Directory.Exists(file)
```

In order to check existence of File you need to use

```
File.Exists(file)
```

Secondly,
You are trying to ReadAllText from the file by passing as parameter the file concatenated with the file name again. So the file name you are passing is actually:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "test.txt" + "\\test.txt";
```

Thirdly, same comment for WriteAllText as for ReadAllText.

There are a lot of examples on the net to learn how to read and write from a file, for example:

[Read from a Text File - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx)
[Write to a Text File - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx)

Comment: You should give meaningful names to your variables. Do not call file to a variable that represents a directory. Call if directoryPath or folderPath for example. After fixing that, do you still have issues?

Comment: I have added a condition to check if file has single quotes.  if (text.Contains("'")). Now I am not getting the exception.